# Find a particular solution to the non-homogeneous differential equation $y''+4y'+5y=−15x+e^{−x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a particular solution to the non-homogeneous differential equation
$$y''+4y'+5y=−15x+e^{−x}$$

I got the homogeneous solution as :
$$
c_1e^{-2x}\cos(x)+c_2e^{-2x}\sin(x)
$$
I am having trouble finding the particular solution

Comment: What methods do you know? Do they include variation-of-constants and method-of-undetermined-parameters?

Comment: You could try with something of the form $y_\mathrm{part}(x)=a x + b e^{-x} +c$, and try to tune the coefficients so as to get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinks of a function $p$ such that when you apply the operator $(D^2+4D+5I)$ to it, you end up with $-15x+e^{-x}$. Surely something like this would have to have the form
$$p(x) = ae^{-x} + bx + c.$$
Then just plug it in to $y''+4y'+5y$, you'll get
$$(D^2+4D+5I)p = 2ae^{-x}+5bx+4b+5c.$$
If you put $a=\frac12$, $b=-3$ and $c=\frac{12}5$, you'll end up with $-15x+e^{-x}$, thus the particular integral you should take is
$$\boxed{p(x) = \tfrac12e^{-x}-3x+\tfrac{12}5.}$$

---

This method (and *why* it works) is explained on pages 2-6 of [these notes](https://drmenguin.com/files/odes.pdf).